# Join only the partitions of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server 2008

Table A looks like:

```
A_ID  v1   v2   v3
---------------------------
 1    d    e    f
 1    a    b    c
 1    a    b    d
 2    d    a    b
 2    e    f    g
 3    d    e    f
 3    e    f    g
 3    d    a    b
```

and Table B is similar:

```
B_ID  v1   v2   v3
---------------------------
 Q    a    b    c
 Q    b    a    c
 Q    a    b    d
 R    d    e    f
 R    a    b    c
 R    d    e    f
 P    e    f    g
 P    d    a    b
```

What I need back from these two tables are the (A_ID, B_ID) pairs, if any, where each row of Table B where B_ID = any one value has one matching row in Table A where A_ID = any one value.  In other words, I need to the complete matching set in A for each full set of triples in B--no super sets or subsets.  The value of B_ID and A_ID is immaterial.

I thought partitioning would be the way to go, since I already have the column that naturally partitions A and B, and I also thought I could pre-select which paritions where JOINed by ensuring only partitions with matching numbers of rows would be attempting. I haven't been able to do either--partitioning both tables was easy, but I see no way to tell the join to only act on the partitions.

In this example, (2,P) would be returned because all rows in Set P match all rows in Set 2. Result (1, R) would NOT be returned because all rows of Set R are not matched by all rows of Set 1, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `symetric difference`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.A_ID, b1.B_ID
FROM A a1,B b1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   (SELECT v1,v2,v3
                   FROM A WHERE A.A_ID = a1.A_ID
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT v1,v2,v3
                   FROM B WHERE B.B_ID = b1.B_ID
                   ) 
                   UNION ALL
                   (
                   SELECT v1,v2,v3
                   FROM B WHERE B.B_ID = b1.B_ID
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT v1,v2,v3
                   FROM A WHERE A.A_ID = a1.A_ID)
                 );
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/XSZZAY4583)**</kbd>

Comment: It works perfectly and rather quickly, too.THAT is pretty cool. Very much appreciated.